# compute loss between to matrices

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, deep-learning, tensorflow2.0, loss-function

In one of google's articles ([EXPLORING TRADEOFFS IN MODELS FOR LOW-LATENCY SPEECH ENHANCEMENT](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1811.07030.pdf)) the use this

[image]

loss function to minimize the error, I have coded this function in Python with Tensorflow,

```
def loss_cal(noise_source, mask, target):
    landa = 0.113
    masked_spec = noise_source*mask
    cc = K.l2_normalize(tf.abs(tf.pow(tf.maximum(1e-4, target), 0.3))-tf.abs(tf.pow(tf.maximum(1e-4, masked_spec), 0.3)))
    cm = K.l2_normalize(tf.math.pow(tf.maximum(1e-4, target), 0.3)-tf.math.pow(tf.maximum(1e-4, masked_spec), 0.3))
    res = tf.math.square(cc)+landa*tf.math.square(cm)
    return res
```

but it returns a matrix, while the loss functions must be returing a scalre, please correct me, is my implementation wrong? or it's possible to train a model with loss as matrix?

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't you be using just [norm](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/norm), not [l2_normalize](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/math/l2_normalize)?

l2_normalize returns a matrix normalized with the norm value.

Comment: but in the article the use l2_normalize

Comment: @WalidBousseta in the formula they use 2-norm (Euclidean norm) which is the default for tf.norm. It's a scalar. l2_normalize normalizes the matrix with 2-norm.